# What kind of JST connectors are needed for the Raspberry Pi 5?

Tags: uart, pwm, rtc, pi-5

All of the documentation I can find for the new JST headers on the Raspberry Pi 5 fails to mention which series of JST connectors it uses.

If I want to make up my own 4-pin PWM fan, 3-pin UART or 2-pin RTC battery cable, which JST connectors do I need?

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi 5 appears to use 1mm JST SH connectors.

I already had some 4-pin JST SH cables (for connecting STEMMA QT boards) and they fit perfectly into the Raspberry Pi 5 4 pin PWM fan header.

JSH SH connectors are very fiddly to crimp however, so I would highly recommend getting pre-crimped cables (connectors at both ends) and cutting them in half to get bare cables, or getting pre-crimped pigtails (connector at one end, bare wires at the other).